# Why this doesn't appear to be initialized

Tags: java, error-handling, nullpointerexception, bufferedimage

I have a typical NullPointerException:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.game.main.SpriteSheet.grabImage(SpriteSheet.java:17)
at com.game.main.Textures.getTextures(Textures.java:30)
at com.game.main.Textures.<init>(Textures.java:21)
at com.game.main.Game.init(Game.java:80)
at com.game.main.Game.run(Game.java:116)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

and I'm pretty sure I know where the null is, I think it's this method (Also this is getImage method loads in whichever grid you want in the spritesheet.png image I created)

```
public BufferedImage grabImage(int column, int row, int width, int height){
        System.out.println("img is " + image); //<<<< How I tested for null.. May not be the best way, but image said to be null

        BufferedImage img = image.getSubimage((column * 32) - 32, (row * 32) - 32, width, height);

        return img;
```

}

I've looked at around about everything in this class, this is the class: SpiteSheet.class

```
package com.game.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

public class SpriteSheet {

private BufferedImage image;

public SpriteSheet(BufferedImage image){
    this.image = image;
    System.out.println("img is " + this.image); // <<<<<<<<< THIS ONE SHOWS "img is nullException in thread "Thread-0" " in the console
}

public BufferedImage grabImage(int column, int row, int width, int height){
    System.out.println("img is " + image); //<<<< How I tested for null.. May not be the best way, but image said to be null

    BufferedImage img = image.getSubimage((column * 32) - 32, (row * 32) - 32, width, height);

    return img; 
}
}
```

And i was wondering how I would be able to initiate it? Although I'm guessing it already is as image.getSubimage(code), I tested this.image and it says that, that is the NullPointerException... But it should be already initiated.

**Some more classes which may be involved**

- Textures.class

  ```
    package com.game.main;

    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

    public class Textures {

      public BufferedImage[] player = new BufferedImage[3];
      public BufferedImage[] missile = new BufferedImage[3];
      public BufferedImage[] enemy = new BufferedImage[3];



      private SpriteSheet ss;
      private Game game;

      public Textures(Game game){
          this.game = game;
          ss = new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet());

          getTextures(); // This is line 21


      }

      public void getTextures(){



      player[0] = ss.grabImage(1, 1, 32, 32); //This is line 30
      player[1] = ss.grabImage(1, 2, 32, 32);
      player[2] = ss.grabImage(1, 3, 32, 32);

      missile[0] = ss.grabImage(2, 1, 32, 32);
      missile[1] = ss.grabImage(2, 2, 32, 32);
      missile[2] = ss.grabImage(2, 3, 32, 32);

      enemy[0] = ss.grabImage(3, 1, 32, 32);
      enemy[1] = ss.grabImage(3, 2, 32, 32);
      enemy[2] = ss.grabImage(3, 3, 32, 32);


  }
  ```

  }

The game.class is pretty big so I'll give the main method it's saying is involved in it(get it? init(), in it...)

- Game.class

  ```
   public void init(){

  requestFocus(); //Brings focus to the screen at the start
  BufferedImageLoader loader = new BufferedImageLoader();
  try{

      spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/Sprite_Sheet.png");
      background = loader.loadImage("/Background.png");

  }catch(IOException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }

  addKeyListener(new KeyInput(this));

  tex = new Textures(this);
  p = new Player(300,300, tex);
  c = new Controller(tex);

  ea = c.getEntityA();
  eb = c.getEntityB();

  c.createEnemy(enemyCount);
  ```

  }

**If you need me to show another class, I will be happy to do so as the biggest and the only big(ish) one is Game**

**EDIT: ** this is the getSpriteSheet method

```
        `public BufferedImage getSpriteSheet(){ return spriteSheet; }`
```

**EDIT1: ** This is the BufferedImageLoader class

```
 package com.game.main;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class BufferedImageLoader {

    private BufferedImage image;

    public BufferedImage loadImage(String path) throws IOException{

        image = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource(path));
        return image;
    }

}
```

**EDIT2: ** When I try to path it from the start, I just get this error, I don't think I've made a mistake while pathing it either. So ill keep it as /Sprite_Sheet.png;

```
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at com.game.main.BufferedImageLoader.loadImage(BufferedImageLoader.java:14)
    at com.game.main.Game.init(Game.java:72)
    at com.game.main.Game.run(Game.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**EDIT3: ** I've checked if it was only spriteSheet loading in something null, and it was, background didn't give back null

**FOUND THE ANSWER: ** I formatted it wrong, although it was PNG, it clearly wasn't right, so I opened it with a different image editor and exported it again.

Comment: can you post the getSpriteSheet method?

Comment: @turingcomplete this is in the Game class public BufferedImage getSpriteSheet(){
  return spriteSheet;
 }

Comment: can you please edit your post and put the code there?. Code in comments is kinda unreadable.

Comment: @turingComplete sorry, my bad. Just forgot

Comment: Seems that BufferedImageLoader is not part of the standard java library. Can you post the code to it or a link to a reference to it?

Comment: The init() code is already posted above, it's right below init()

Comment: I am talking about the BufferedImageLoader class. I suspect that you entered an incorrect path to the image, the BufferedImageLoader class couldn't find it, and thus the image was set to null.

Comment: Whoops, that was obvious you were asking for a class. My bad, I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `Game.spriteSheet` member has not yet been initialized when `ss = new SpriteSheet(game.getSpriteSheet())` is called, which is triggered by `tex = new Textures(this)` in `Game.init()`.

The odd thing is that in `Game.init()`, the `spriteSheet` is initialized before `new Texture(this)` is called.  Can you check that `spriteSheet` is not null after the try/catch block with `spriteSheet = loader.loadImage("/Sprite_Sheet.png")` in `Game.init()`.

Comment: Actually, the problem is probably in `loader.loadImage("/Sprite_Sheet.png");`, where `loader` is a `BufferedImageLoader`.  That method must be constructing and returning a `SpriteSheet(null)`.  You should add some checks in that method.  As @turingcomplete mentioned, it's likely a path problem.

Comment: How would I go about to fixing that? (Sorry for being stupid yet again)Ah right :S

Comment: Add code that checks that you did read the file.  Something must have failed and you got a null.  We don't have to the code for that method.

Comment: Oh! I just noticed: "/Sprite_Sheet.png".   The leading slash means it will look at the very root of your filesystem.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that I'm working on a mac, it worked before I tried adding some animation. The png is in a file called "res" in the project folder

Comment: yep, I did a simple if statement after the image should've been loaded and it said null, I'll try and path it a bit more in-depth I suppose

Comment: I tried to path it from the start instead of just going /Sprite_Sheet.png; but I got the error I posted above